# Global vs. local function object

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that returns another function, which captures the parameter of the wrapper function. the local version works, but the global version doesn't, and I don't understand why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


const auto& parseDateTimeWithFormat = [](const std::string& formatStr) {
    return [&formatStr](const std::string& dateTimeStr) {
        std::cout << formatStr << std::endl;
        tm t = {};
        std::istringstream ss(dateTimeStr);
        ss >> std::get_time(&t, formatStr.c_str());
        const int timestamp = (int)mktime(&t);
        return timestamp;
    };
};


const auto& parseDateTime1 = parseDateTimeWithFormat("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int ts1 = parseDateTime1("2018-10-08T10:09:08Z");
    std::cout << ts1 << std::endl;

    const auto& parseDateTime2 = parseDateTimeWithFormat("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
    int ts2 = parseDateTime2("2018-10-08T10:09:08Z");
    std::cout << ts2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
(empty string)
-1
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
1538989748
```

also, when capturing `formatStr` by value instead of by reference, the global version works, too.

Comment: Because you are capturing a reference to local parameter, which itself is a reference to temporary and is destroyed after the function returns.

Comment: `parseDateTimeWithFormat` can be just a regular function. Note that lambdas in c++ are not some kind of "higher-order function".

Comment: seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @VTT you are right, it's actually not a higher order function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local version might "work" but it also suffers from the same thing as the global version, which is undefined behavior.  In all cases when you call `parseDateTimeWithFormat` you give a string literal.  Since that isn't a `std::string` a temporary one is created for you.  That string is what you capture in

```
return [&formatStr](const std::string& dateTimeStr) {
    std::cout << formatStr << std::endl;
    tm t = {};
    std::istringstream ss(dateTimeStr);
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, formatStr.c_str());
    const int timestamp = (int)mktime(&t);
    return timestamp;
};
```

and return out of the lambda.  Unfornetly, as soon as the expresion ends where you called `parseDateTimeWithFormat` that temporary is destroyed and you are left with a dangling reference to `formatStr`.  The fix, like you found, is to capture by value so the lambda has it's own copy and you don't try to refer to something that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: What Nathan said! :)